# Crear nuevas tablas en laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Soy nueva en laravel y tengo un problema
Tengo ya creado una base de datos con 3 tablas con datos llenados y cuando creo una nueva migración quiero añadir la nueva tabla.
estaba usando

`php artisan migrate:refresh`

pero esa me actualiza y borra los datos llegados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pues de seguro estas usando

```
php artisan make:migration create_ejemplos_table --create=ejemplos
```

ahora para añadir una nueva tabla puedes ejecutar el comando

```
php artisan make:migration add_nueva_tabla_table --table=nueva_tabla
```

y ejecutas `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente debes crear una nueva migración con la nueva tabla y ejecutar `php artisan migrate` , sin ningún otro sufijo, para ejecutar las migraciones que tengas pendientes.

Toda la documentación en el sitio de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations